# In what cases, Secure.ANDROID_ID will be useful?

Tags: android, unique

I want to know what is the purpose of ANDROID_ID and when to use it? In what cases it will be useful?

Answer (score 0):

A small search on Google could very useful..... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID
There is explained what the ANDROID_ID is and where/when it remains unique (Android 8+) and when it is reset after at each Android reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

[Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html) article provides two use cases:

> **Track signed-out user preferences between apps with the same signing key**
>
> In this case, you're saving per-device state on the server side
>   and transferring it between different apps that are signed with the
>   same key on the same device.
>
> **Use:** SSAID
>
> **Why this recommendation?**
>
> In Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, SSAID provides an identifier
>   that's common between apps signed by the same developer signing key.
>   It allows you to share state between these apps without requiring the
>   user to sign-in to an account.

and

> **Anti-fraud: Enforcing free content limits and detecting Sybil attacks**
>   In this case, you want to limit the number of free content, such as
>   articles, that a user can see on a device.
>
> **Use:** Instance ID or GUID. On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher,
>   SSAID is also an option, as it's scoped to the app-signing key.
>
> **Why this recommendation?**
>
> Using a GUID or Instance ID forces the user to reinstall the app in
>   order to circumvent the content limits, which is a sufficient burden
>   to deter most people. If this isn't sufficient protection, Android
>   provides a DRM API, which can be used to limit access to content,
>   includes a per-APK identifier, the Widevine ID.

For those wondering how SSAID relates to ANDROID_ID, SSAID = **S**ecure.**S**torage.**A**NDROID_**ID**.